# How to buy Japanese baseball tickets from the US?

Tags: japan, tickets, hotels, mail, sports-events

What's a good way to buy Japanese baseball tickets from the US?

I'm trying to get tickets to the 4/13 Tigers game at Koshien stadium in Osaka. I can read Japanese, and would love to buy from the Tigers' [website](http://hanshintigers.jp/ticket/koshien/), but their vendors can only mail to Japanese addresses.

So far my only bet is [this guy](http://www.japanballtickets.com), who buys tickets and delivers them to your hotel. The downside is that he charges $60 extra per order, and you can't choose your seat section; you can only choose between "good", "better", and "best" seats.

Are there other options?

For example: could I just order from the Tigers' website and have them deliver to my hotel, 3 weeks before I get there? Or do hotels not do that?

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Don't they have a "will call" option?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Online sales are handled exclusively through resellers, who either mail them to you, or have you pick them up at convenience stores: "チケットの引取はサークルK・サンクス、チケットぴあ店舗のみとなります" / "Ticket pickup is limited to Circle K, Thanks, and TicketPia stores". From: http://www.hanshin.co.jp/koshien/ticket/regular.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that hotels are happy to receive mail for you before you arrive, provided you give them a heads-up first. I just bought my tickets from the Tigers' [website](http://hanshintigers.jp/ticket/tt/), and had them send it to my hotel. I added my arrival date to the address, as "Lastname樣　(4月8日宿泊)". The hotel got it fine.

I did have to provide a Japanese phone number to the ticket purchasing website. My Japanese Skype number wasn't accepted (maybe because it has an area code specific to VoIP numbers). I used my friends' number, but I imagine you could just use your hotel's number; it's not like they got a call.

Answer (score 4):

The quick google of the subject yields:

- [Japanese BaseBall Tickets](http://www.japanesebaseballtickets.com/buytickets.html)
- [Japanese Baseball](http://www.japanesebaseball.com/faq/tickets.gsp) - This site talks specifically about Japanese Baseball

Apparently the one you mentioned and the one I listed first are the only 2 selling Japanese baseball tickets in the US.