# Can you receive mail at hotels weeks before you arrive?

Tags: japan, hotels, mail

Do hotels accept mail for guests that haven't arrived yet? Even weeks in advance?

I am buying tickets for an event (see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6232/how-to-buy-japanese-baseball-tickets-from-the-us)), but the vendor can only mail tickets to a Japanese address. I don't arrive in Japan for another 2 weeks, but I want to buy the tickets now before they sell out.

Do hotels accept mail for guests 2 weeks in advance?

Comment: generally "yes" - but of course, this applies mote at 4-star hotels, than at inexpensive hotels.  note that if you, simply, phoned or emailed the hotel saying "Oh, you may get a letter for me" that would help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no single answer to this, as different hotels have different policies.

In general most hotels will be happy to store mail and small packages for you for a short time. Most will ask that you mark that fact you're a guest as a part of the address, and I've had at least 2 hotels that requested that my arrival date also be listed as a part of the address.

Some hotels will charge you a fee for this service, especially if what you're receiving is anything more than just a standard letter.

Normally the item will be held for you at the front desk/concierge (often with a note on your booking so that they know it's there when you check-in), although at some hotels they will store it in the "Business Center" which can cause issues if you're planning to arrive outside of the business centers hours.

The best plan is to either email or call the hotel in advance to confirm their local policies - I've never had a hotel not respond to such an email with the relevant details, plus you end up with a record of what they told you in case there's any problems later on (such as one hotel where I was told there was no charge, but then they tried to charge me when I got there!)

Comment: Thanks. I e-mailed the hotel, and they were indeed fine with it, with no charge. They didn't request that I put my arrival date on the envelope, but I did, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should call the hotel and ask them, they probably would hold the tickets for you provided you ask the vendor to mention it on the envelop (write "for pickup by guest" or something).

I had my mail sent to a hotel in the US, they held it for me.