# How long does it take for letters to get from Osaka to Tokyo?

Tags: japan, tokyo, mail, osaka

I would like to order tickets to be mailed from Osaka to my hotel in Tokyo. How long should I expect it to take? It'll be mailed by standard post (no express charges).

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'd call a "Travel" question...

Comment: I'm staying at a hotel for only a few days, and whether a ticket arrives during that time will affect how I plan my travel. With your answer, hopefully more travelers to Japan will feel confident to purchase tickets and have them sent to hotels by post (see also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6233/395).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://www.post.japanpost.jp/cgi-deli/index.php (Japanese only) a standard letter from Osaka to Tokyo will be delivered "next day".

Comment: My experience corroborates Letters / Postcards being next day delivery (as long as it is posted by 4PM (the last mail pickup of the day). Note that mail can be delivered as late as 9PM. Large packages take 2 days if they are sent by Yamato Takubin over a similar distance (ie. A bicycle, Kobe > Chiba)